How to create a custom severity from allure-pytest?
I use the libraries allure-pytest=2.13.2 and allure-python-commons=2.13.2 to build an allure-report. I need to change the set of severity values ​​(add "high" and "low"). I can't do this.
The library has these values:
class Severity(str, Enum):
    BLOCKER = 'blocker'
    CRITICAL = 'critical'
    NORMAL = 'normal'
    MINOR = 'minor'
    TRIVIAL = 'trivial'

If I do this:
@allure.label('severity', 'high')

then the report displays "normal" (the default value).
By the way, no labels are displayed in the report at all, apparently this is a bug.
So how can I make my own values ​​for severity? Has anyone encountered this problem?

It looks likeallure hardcoded Severity alues
 if tag in [severity for severity in Severity]:
    return Label(name=LabelType.SEVERITY, value=tag)

Your could create an issue for allure
https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/blob/20ba28a086e9097c4d44f9e01c8df8bf85f41d3e/allure-python-commons/src/mapping.py#L56
